# TED-LIUM transcripts (text files only)

Tags: data-request

Where can I find just the text files of the TED-LIUM v2 corpus, without the audio?

The [official site](http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/en/content/ted-lium-corpus) has everything in one huge file (~30GB), which I'd rather not download.